# Divisão Euclidiana

Tags: c++, matemática

Existe um problema da divisão Euclidiana em que o resto `r` não pode ser maior que o `b`, seguindo o teorema `a = b.q + r`.

Eu fiz um código e recebi um *accepted*, mas encontrei um melhor que o meu!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;


int main(){

    int a,b,q,r;

    cin>>a>>b;
    q = a/b;
    r = a - b*q;

    if(r < 0)
        r = r + abs(b);

    q = (a-r)/b;
    cout<<q<<" "<<r<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Alguém sabe como chego a conclusão que se `r < 0`, o novo resto é `r = r - b` ou `r = r - |b|`?

Comment: Amigo, tá difícil de entender qual é a sua dificuldade. O que é "um novo resto"? A frase sozinha, do jeito que está, não faz sentido. Edite a pergunta e melhore-a, pois não está nada claro. Explique também se o seu problema é matemático ou de programação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine que queiramos dividir [image: a] chocolates para [image: b] crianças de forma que cada criança receba [image: q] chocolates e que sobrem [image: r] chocolates no final. Se tivermos que [image: r >= b], então desses [image: r] chocolates restantes, poderíamos pegar mais [image: b] chocolates e dar mais um para cada criança, o que significa que cada criança receberia [image: q + 1] chocolates, uma contradição. Logo temos provado que [image: r < b] para valores positivos.

Para valores negativos, isso pode ser generalizado como [image: |r| < |b|]. A prova por contradição seria parecida com a anterior, onde poderíamos distribuir um excedente de [image: +-b] itens do suposto resto e alterando o suposto quociente.

Sendo então [image: a=b.q+r], logo [image: a-r=b.q], consequentemente [image: -r=b.q-a] e finalmente[image: r=a-b.q].

Agora, vamos ao seu programa.
Primeiro:

```
r = a - b*q;
```

Ora, isso é exatamente o que está na equação acima.

Também podemos deduzir que se [image: r>0], então [image: a>b.q]. Se [image: r>0], então [image: a<b.q]. Disso dá para se chegar ao testar as quatro combinações de sinais de [image: a] e [image: b] (e também o zero para [image: a]) que [image: |a|>=|b.q|] e com isso que [image: |a|-|b.q|>=0].

Também dá para se concluir a partir de [image: |a|>=|b.q|] que [image: (sgn(a-b.q)=sgn(a) ou a = b.q)], e com isso [image: (sgn(r)=sgn(a) ou r=0)].

Assim sendo, para que tenhamos [image: r<0], é porque [image: a<0]. E é nesse caso que se entra no `if`.

Dentro do `if`, sabemos que [image: r < 0]. Assim sendo, temos que [image: r+|b|=|b|-|r|=r_{novo}]. Uma vez que [image: |r| < |b|], então [image: |b| - |r| > 0] e com isso [image: r_{novo}>0].

Ter a hipótese de que [image: |b| - |r| >= |b|] é absurda porque significaria que [image: |r| <= 0], e o resultado de um módulo não pode ser negativo e o caso do zero não entra nesse `if`. Assim sendo, temos que [image: |b| - |r| < |b|] e portanto [image: r_{novo} < |b|].

Se não entrar no `if`, o próprio [image: |r| < |b|] já garante que [image: r >= 0] porque módulos não podem ser negativos, e essa condição também o impede de alcançar ou ultrapassar o valor de [image: |b|].

Unificando os casos em que entra ou não no `if`, temos que [image: 0 <= r_{final} < |b|].

O caso onde o módulo faz diferença dentro do `if` é quando [image: a < 0] e [image: b < 0].

O valor somado ao resto dentro do `if` está correto porque ao somar [image: |b|], é como se fingíssimos que um chocolate a mais foi dado para cada criança, o que deve deixar o resto resultante igual. Como já explicado acima, isso não viola a condição de que [image: |r| < |b|], e de fato, serve exatamente para colocar o valor do resto na faixa esperada, e portanto fica tudo certo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta!! está bem completa!

Mas de fato fiquei horas pensando e não cheguei a conclusão matemática que r + b = R novo, todas as outras hipóteses eu consegui enxergar. Grato